# How to get only ip addresses from the echo stat command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, apache-zookeeper

When I am executing the below command

```
echo stat | nc localhost 2181
```

I am getting

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
Clients:
/10.999.87.01:56046[1](queued=0,recved=95261,sent=95261)
/10.888.98.02:47356[1](queued=0,recved=45856,sent=45856)
/10.777.09.03:53636[1](queued=0,recved=96378,sent=96380)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/316
Received: 3034250
Sent: 3035252
Connections: 3
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x21000351cf
Mode: follower
Node count: 2740
```

Can anyone help me to separate the ip addresses as below by using commands

```
10.999.87.01
10.888.98.02
10.777.09.03
```

So my question is do we have any commands for this. If yes please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
... nc .... | awk -F: '/^[\/]/{sub(/^[\/]/,"",$1);print $1}'
```

**output**

```
10.999.87.01
10.888.98.02
10.777.09.03
```

Comment: then your output is not as you indicate in your Q. Or it contains `\r\n` line endings. Check for that with `.... nc .... | cat -vet`. If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, let me know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to perform this using SED, AWK, Grep, Bash, Perl, or other languages. But I prefer Perl for text processing, as it is definitely the most flexible tool for this task.

Simple expression based on `/` and `:` markers:

```
your-command | perl -ne '/^\/([^:]+):/ and print "$1\n"'
```

Strict pattern matching (which will look very complex with the above-mentioned tools (or even unavailable on some platforms):

```
your-command | perl -ne '/^\/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):/ and print "$1\n"'
```

Comment: @Manikya, it [actually works](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMREFmSmhQMGtVR0E)!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[/:]' 'NR>2&&NR<6{print $2}' ipaddresses

10.999.87.01
10.888.98.02
10.777.09.03
```